# ompi_evesel->dispatch() failed when running OpenMPI process from Java ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, python, windows, processbuilder, openmpi

I am trying to create a Java GUI to control and run an MPI process. I can run an MPI process from my command line, but am unable to run via the Java Process Builder.

I get the following error immediately after the process starts:

```
[SCI053_VM003:02928] ..\..\openmpi-1.6.4\opal\event\event.c: ompi_evesel->dispatch() failed.
```

I suspect there is an environment problem, but I am not sure how to diagnose it. I have printed the environment seen by the java process builder to the log as well as the environment seen by the mpiexec'd process, but I see nothing amiss!?!?

All the code and the output log are posted on [gist](https://gist.github.com/dstuebe/6067520)

I am trying to run in a windows environment using OpenMPI 1.6.4 packaged for [MPI4PY](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mpi4py)

Seems like mostly an OpenMPI problem, so I posted to the [UserList](http://www.open-mpi.org/community/lists/users/2013/07/22376.php), but hoping for help anywhere I can get it...

David

PS - I am able to run the Java program to launch and run the same code in my MacOS environment, but there I use brew installed MPICH2.

Comment: I will be testing calling mpiexec using python subprocess today. If this turns out to be a workable intermediary Java ProcessBuilder => Python Subprocess => OpenMPI MPIExec => run my parallel application... I will use it, but it doesn't really answer my question (or the bounty)

Comment: Update: I wrote a short python program to call mpiexec or whatever commands you pass it. It works great from the command line:

Comment: Update: I wrote a short python program to call mpiexec or whatever commands you pass it. https://gist.github.com/dstuebe/6170563
It works great as an indirection to run any program from the command line but it fails the same way when I use it from inside ProcessBuilder in Java!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the issue is because you're using Windows. I don't remember when OpenMPI stopped supporting Windows, but at some point it did. You might try using Microsoft's port of MPICH that works on Windows and see if that does what you need. I don't remember the URL offhand, but you can find the port at the MPICH downloads page (http://www.mpich.org/downloads/).

Comment: It works if I run the job in the cmd window - I won't call it a terminal 'cause it sucks too much... But it does 'work' in windows, just not when I exec it from java.

Comment: Ah. Well in that case, my expertise is lost. I'm far from a Windows/Java person.

Comment: I think I may be screwed if I need to find someone who is an expert in Windows, Java and OpenMPI let alone Python and MPI4py...

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately there just aren't that many people who are really trying to use MPI in Windows. There aren't really any big Windows clusters anymore so no one takes it seriously.

Answer (score 0):

I could also not directly say why, but my expierence with System processes under java is that its best to handle it by some one else.

Here is my tip. I always your apache commins exec when calling external applications.
Link to the basics tutorial http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/tutorial.html
Hopefully it helps. Its easy to implement and to use.

Just finished reading your gist. What i was missing is, where you set your working directory.
Try setting the working directory to the directory where you were possible to launch from command line.

Comment: I can run in the same working directory from the command line just fine. You can see the working directory in the output from env.py - which gets executed just fine - but MPI craps out and mpi programs like bcast.py won't work.

I will try apache commons-exec as a last resort. I already have a lot of code written around ProcessBuilder.
Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

When you run mpiexec.exe successfully from cmd.exe, what directory are you in? I'm curious about the LD_LIBRARY_PATH shown in your output log... it is odd that LD_LIBRARY_PATH is being set on Windows:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\mpi4py\bin/../lib:C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\mpi4py\bin\..\lib
```

Does launching mpiexec.exe work from Windows when you set your PATH variable to point to the MPI bin and lib directories? I'm not positive if [these Open MPI instructions apply](http://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=running#adding-ompi-to-path), but they mention setting PATH environment variable.

Comment: Tried adding the path to the ProcessBuilder environ and I can see it in the output from env.py but I still get the error from mpiexec.